# Write latex equation inside knitr chunks

Tags: r, latex, knitr, equation

I am trying to write a equation inside a chunk. I need to use `'\sum'` but R does not accept it. I got the error:

```
'\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string
```

I also tried some packages without success.

How can I bay pass this escape character?

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<results='asis',echo=FALSE>>=
#library(lazyWeave)
#library(hwriterPlus)
 #hwriteLatex(as.latex("\bar{R}_{i}=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{T}{R_{i,t}}}{8}"))
#
cat('\bar{R}_{i}=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{T}{R_{i,t}}}{8}')

#cat("$$","\bar{R}_{i}=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{T}{R_{i,t}}}{8}","$$",sep="")

cat("Typically we want our paragraphs to be left
justified. This is often what we expect to see when reading.")

@

\end{document}
```

Edit. I read some similar examples but no one involved escape characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double the escape character.

```
> cat('\\bar{R}_{i}=\\frac{\\sum_{t=1}^{T}{R_{i,t}}}{8}')
\bar{R}_{i}=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{T}{R_{i,t}}}{8}>
```

Comment: Great! This works: `cat('$$\\bar{R}_{i}=\\frac{\\sum_{t=1}^{T}{R_{i,t}}}{8}$$')`.